# Javascripts escape quotes

Tags: javascript, php

I have table named posts and if add title named in quotes ("This the new")  to posts table. And when I delete this posts from table I have this onclick js:

```
echo "<td><a class='btn btn-danger' href=\"javascript:delpost('".$row['postID']."', '".$row['postTitle']."')\">Delete</a></td>";
```

But as I say whenever I add title in quotes ("this the new")

javascript is gave me this:

```
<a href="javascript:delpost('$row', ' " this="" the="" new" ')"=""> Delete</a>
```

That reason delete script can't work.
What should I do? How to escape if given string between in quotes.

Comment: To have a string contain a literal double quote, either quote with single quotes, or use `\"` eg: `"The main said \"Hello,\" and went on his way"`

Comment: <td><a class='btn btn-danger' href=\"javascript:delpost('".$row['postID']."', \"'".$row['postTitle']."'\")\">Delete</a></td> look like that? @CollinD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the correct way to do it

```
echo '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:delpost(\''.$row['postID'].'\', \''.htmlspecialchars($row['postTitle'], ENT_QUOTES).'\')">Delete</a></td>';
```

Comment: what's the output? after this

Comment: on dom: href="javascript:delpost('9', '" this="" the="" new"')"

Comment: It works thanks. But its not works for single quotes so what should I do for single quotes.

Comment: simple add `htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES)` this will escape single quote as well, also if this is help please accept answer